# get id from previous page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is My Code now

```
SESSION_START();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';
    $id             = $_POST['id'];
    $fullname       = $_POST['fullname'];
    $kategori       = $_POST['kategori'];
    $lokasi         = $_POST['lokasi'];
    $masaberlaku    = $_POST['masaberlaku'];
    $tipe           = $_POST['tipe'];
    $deskripsi      = $_POST['deskripsi'];
    $teknologi      = $_POST['teknologi'];


    mysql_query     ("UPDATE activity SET fullname ='$fullname' WHERE id_activity ='$id'" );
    mysql_query     ("UPDATE item INNER JOIN activity SET item.namaitem = activity.fullname WHERE activity.item_id = item.item_id") ;
    header("Location: modelingform.php?id=$id");
    }
```

What I ask is, can i get the $id at the bottom being send to the next page?

so i get directed into `modelingform.php?id=1`

what i get now is `modelingform.php?id=%201`

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: For your requirement,i think you need to maintain Session.

Comment: Session for what adarsh ?^^

Comment: please check for space are you passing id with space? I think %20 is noramlly coming when space included. Also you can use urlencode(). @Rizal

Comment: so what i have to write @fabio ?

Comment: which part @RuchishParikh ? in the process page or in the destination page?

Comment: use urlencode in the process page from where you are specifying redirecting url. @Rizal

Comment: Try with this urlencode(trim(intval($id))). @Rizal

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @RuchishParikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function for `$id`

**Example:**

```
header("Location: modelingform.php?id=".urlencode(trim($id)));
```

In `urlencode()` space encode with (+) , you also need to use `trim()` for removing spaces.

Comment: it's working but after redirect i got this url, it contained + 

modelingform.php?id=+1 this is the result

Comment: @Rizal: containing `id=+1`??

Comment: or maybe there's another way to pass the id? using other way?

Comment: yes, u have extra space in your variable... `urlencode(trim($id))` ... use this. @Rizal

Comment: thanks a lot @devpro you're so genius... once again thankyou

Comment: @Rizal: glad to help u, and thank you for editing.. i have mentioned the trim()